# Behavior of the roots of an infinite series.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, power-series

I have the polynomial $P_n(z)=1-\sum_{k=1}^{n}z^k$. We know that this polynomial has exactly $n$ roots in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\rho$ be the number of roots of $P_n$, thence if $n\to\infty$ then $\rho$ must tend to $\infty$ too. Though, if we interpret the sum as a geometric series, we get that
$$P_n(z)=1-\sum_{k=1}^{n}z^k=\frac{z^{n+1}-2z+1}{1-z}$$
And if we make $n\to\infty$ it only converges for $|z|<1$, becoming $P_\infty(z)=-\frac{2z-1}{1-z}$, that has only one real root for $z=\frac{1}{2}$. So, where did the other roots go? I plotted $P_n$ variating $n$ and noted that the roots tend to accumulate on the unit disk. ([Interactive Mapping](https://samuelj.li/complex-function-plotter/#(z%5E(t%2B1)-2*z%2B1)%2F(1-z))). So, can we say that all the roots will accumulate on the unit disk as $n\to\infty$ for $z\neq1$? How can we prove this? Thanks!

Here I have some screenshots of the mapping. Respectively, $n=5$, $n=10$, $n=100$. You can see that the roots tend to accumulate towards the unit circle.

### | [image: n=5]  [image: n=10] [image: n=100] |

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for drawing our attention to https://samuelj.li/complex-function-plotter/

Comment: The limit expression is only valid for $|z|<1$. Also note that in the complex numbers, there is no order, so "$-1<z<1$" makes only sense for real numbers.

Comment: You can simplify this example by removing a few superfluous terms: $z^n-1$ converges to $-1$. Where do the roots go?

Comment: @Arthur it converges to -1 iff $|z|<1$. For $|z|=1$ we have $1^\infty$, but can we manage to solve the limit as $n\to\infty$ to get that the infinite roots lie on the unit disk?

Comment: @Peter you're right. Edited in $|z|<1$

Comment: Technically, order n polynomials are guaranteed to have n roots only if we consider multiplicities, but that doesn't affect the answer to your question.

Comment: @Acccumulation I can demonstrate that our polynomial has indeed multiple roots, therefore the same number as the order of the polynomial.

Comment: I'm not sure what "multiplicities" means. The polynomial $x^2$ has only one root ($x=0$), but it's a multiple root.

Comment: @Acccumulation I mean, it has separate roots. So it has exactly n roots.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can be proved using [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem).

Let $0 < \epsilon < 1/2$, and take $N$ large enough that
$$
(1-\epsilon)^{N+1} < 1-2\epsilon
\quad\text{and}\quad
(1+\epsilon)^{N+1} > 3 + 2 \epsilon
.
$$
Then for any $n \ge N$ we have
$$
(1-\epsilon)^{n+1} < 1-2\epsilon
\quad\text{and}\quad
(1+\epsilon)^{n+1} > 3 + 2 \epsilon
$$
too, and I will show that this implies that the annulus $1-\epsilon \le |z| < 1+\epsilon$ contains all roots of $f(z) = 2z-1-z^{n+1}$ except $z=1/2$.

Let
$$
g(z) = 2z-1 = 2(z-\tfrac12)
,\qquad
h(z) = -z^{n+1}
.
$$
Then on the circle $|z|=1-\epsilon$, the point closest to $1/2$ is $z=1-\epsilon$, so we have
$$
|g(z)| = 2 |z-\tfrac12| \ge 2 \bigl((1-\epsilon) - \tfrac12 \bigr) = 1 - 2 \epsilon
,
$$
and $|h(z)|=(1-\epsilon)^{n+1}$, so according to the inequalities above we have $|h(z)|<|g(z)|$ on the circle, which according to Rouché means that $f=g+h$ has equally many zeros inside the circle as $g$, namely one (the only zero of $g$ is at $1/2$).

On the other hand, on the circle $|z|=1+\epsilon$, the point furthest from $1/2$ is $z=-1-\epsilon$, so we have
$$
|g(z)| = 2 |z-\tfrac12| \le 2 \bigl|(-1-\epsilon) - \tfrac12 \bigr| = 3 + 2 \epsilon
,
$$
and $|h(z)|=(1+\epsilon)^{n+1}$, so according to the inequalities above we have $|h(z)|>|g(z)|$ on the circle, which according to Rouché means that $f=g+h$ has equally many zeros inside the circle as $h$, namely $n+1$ (since $h$ has a zero of that multiplicity at the origin).

Thus, for any $n \ge N$, the function $f$ has $n$ of its $n+1$ zeros in the annulus between those two circles, of radius $1 \pm \epsilon$. And $\epsilon$ can be chosen arbitrarily small to begin with, which shows that the zeros do accumulate on the unit circle.

Comment: This is great! My numerical testing suggests that apart from that single zero  $\approx 1/2$ the rest of them are actually outside of the unit circle (unless you leave the $z-1$ uncancelled which then produces a single zero on the unit circle). Any thoughts about how to see that (if true)?

Comment: Those zeros satisfy
$$z^n+\frac1z=2.$$
For real $x$ the function $x^n+1/x$ is increasing when $x>n^{-1/(n+1)}$. If $\epsilon$ rules out zeros below that threshold, it follows that $|z|\ge1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: If you try Rouché on the circle $|z|=1$ instead of $|z|=1-\epsilon$, you still get $|h|<|g|$ on the whole circle, *except* at the point $z=1$, and I think (although I haven't thought very carefully about it) that it might be possible to get $|h|<|g|$ on the contour consisting of the unit circle except with an arbitrary small indentation going just inside $z=1$. If that's correct, the $n$ “large” zeros would indeed be one at $z=1$ and the rest outside the unit circle.